# PyTesseract not Detecting Numbers from Video (OCR)

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm running a program that can extract text from a video. I'm trying to use it but I want to extract numbers, instead of pure letters. It's not doing it properly. What can I do regarding this? Included below is the 'extraction' part of the code and a screenshot of one of the frames from my video:

```
def get_text():
    for i in os.listdir(image_frames):
       print(str(i))
       my_example = Image.open(image_frames + "/" + i)
       text = pytesseract.image_to_string(my_example, config='--              psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789') #, config='--psm 6 digits')
    print(text)`
```

I tried to convert it to black and white, but the background and text would be the same color still.